# grep a variable containing special characters

Tags: linux, bash, grep

i'm new to bash scripting and i have to determine if a process is running in a linux environment.
Actually i use the follow command to do the job:

```
#ps -ef | awk '{print substr($0, index($0,$8))}' | grep -v grep | grep -w -F $PROCESSNAME
```

where

```
awk '{print substr($0, index($0,$8))}'
```

allow me to ignore UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY  TIME fields and

```
grep -v grep
```

allow me to ignore the row that contains the command itself. So at this point i have a list of all processes running on the system.

Finally:

```
 grep -w -F $PROCESSNAME
```

read a variable which contains the name of the process that i want to check.
For what i understand the full command should return only the row that has the exact value of $PROCESSNAME

Actually this doesn't works correctly for processes that follow the pattern "[processname]", and probably also for other patterns.

For example to simplify, if i have a running process named "[vmmemctl]" and i run:

```
#ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep -w -F "vmmemctl]"
```

it actually returns a result:

```
#root       615     2  0 Feb26 ?        00:01:00 [vmmemctl]
```

but the actual process name in the command is different from the process name in the result. 
What is the correct command that doesn't have this behavior?

Thank you

Comment: Just use `pgrep` and call it a day..

Comment: or `pidof`, or ...

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
ps -ef | awk '$8=="[command]"{NF=8;print}'
```

or

```
ps -ef | awk -v c="vmmemctl]" '$8==c{NF=8;print}'
```

note that this is for an exact match not pattern.

since this is an exact match the command can have spaces and other special chars in it (it's not pattern match but string equality).  Using your variable name it will look like this

```
ps -ef | awk -v c="$PROCESSNAME" '$8==c{NF=8;print}'
```

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't work. What i need is the command that returns (if exists) only the row with the process name that matches exactly the string contained in the variable $PROCESSNAME. A process name can also have blank spaces. for example in my environment i have a process named  "/sbin/rsyslogd -i /var/run/syslogd.pid -c 5". Thank you anyway.

Comment: that's exactly the point.  It's not a pattern match but exact string equality